# Uploading an UIImage to REST API with Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, swift5

I can send (upload) a picture to REST API with Postman. But I can't send(upload) a picture with `Swift` code in to REST API.

First of all, I would like to share the raw data working with Postman:

```
 POST http://testwlbyp.abc.com/ebys-servis-rest/ebys
 200
 583 ms
 POST /ebys-servis-rest/ebys HTTP/1.1
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.25.0
 Accept: */*
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Postman-Token: 888b7a05-e796-447f-9f6f-f3265bc38f3d
 Host: testwlbyp.abc.com
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 Connection: keep-alive
 Cookie: JSESSIONID=tZXqTQrm8CHDiALd42cIWIiyVctFPSCJMKh-nxIyfqnVLu4CXChe!-1356762059
 Content-Length: 11450
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="p_type"

 LOAD_DOC
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="doc_no"

 20200006966
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

 4268260b012c51fe8b2d41fe4c48e289
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="theme_no"

 63
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="all_parameters"

 FILE_NAME='myTest.jpg'
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profile_no"

 A-S
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ss_no"

 M1997069
 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="user_agent"


 ----------------------------postman
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="testpic.jpg"

 <myTest.jpg>
 ----------------------------postman--
```

Here is the response:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Date: Thu, 25 Jun 2020 08:00:15 GMT
 Content-Length: 169
 Content-Type: application/json
 {
   "LOGID": 282659,
   "RESULTID": "20200006966",
   "FILESIZE": -1,
   "OPNAME": "LOAD_DOC",
   "ERRORCODE": 0,
   "ERRORMESSAGE": "success"
 }
```

And here is the Swift Code;

```
 func uploadPicture(paramaterImage: UIImage, parameterDocNo: String, parameterToken: String, parameterSSNo: String)
    {
        print("LOG 01") // I SEE THIS LOG
    
    let fileName = "testImageName.jpg"
    let oall_param : String = "FILE?_NAME='\(fileName+".jpg")'"

    let url = URL(string: "http://testwlbyp.abc.com/ebys-servis-rest/ebys")
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    
    print("LOG 02") // I SEE THIS LOG
    
    let image = paramaterImage
    let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.7)!
    let qstr = String(decoding: data, as: UTF8.self)
    
    // 1
    urlRequest.addValue("LOAD_DOC", forHTTPHeaderField: "p_type")
    
    // 2
    urlRequest.addValue(parameterDocNo, forHTTPHeaderField: "doc_no")
    
    // 3
    urlRequest.addValue(parameterToken, forHTTPHeaderField: "token")
    
    // 4
    urlRequest.addValue("63123", forHTTPHeaderField: "theme_no")
    
    // 5
    urlRequest.addValue(oall_param, forHTTPHeaderField: "all_parameters")
    
    // 6
    urlRequest.addValue("A-S", forHTTPHeaderField: "profile_no")
    
    // 7
    urlRequest.addValue(parameterSSNo, forHTTPHeaderField: "ss_no")
    
    // 8
    urlRequest.addValue("", forHTTPHeaderField: "user_agent")
    
    // 9
    urlRequest.addValue(qstr, forHTTPHeaderField: "file")
    
    
    let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
    urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    
    print("LOG 03") // I SEE THIS LOG

    
    //create body
    let body = NSMutableData()
    
    //append first line
    let line1_boundryPrefix = "--\(boundary)\r\n"
    body.append(line1_boundryPrefix.data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    //append second line
    let line2_parameter = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"source\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"\r\n"
    body.append(line2_parameter.data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    //append third line (mime type)
    let mimeType = "image/jpg"
    let line3_contentType = "Content-Type: \(mimeType)\r\n\r\n"
    body.append(line3_contentType.data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    //append image data
    //line4
    body.append(data)
    
    
    let line5 = "\r\n"
    body.append(line5.data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    
    
    let line6 = "--" + boundary + "--\r\n"
    body.append(line6.data(
        using: String.Encoding.utf8,
        allowLossyConversion: false)!)
    urlRequest.httpBody = body as Data
    urlRequest.setValue(String(body.length), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
        //handle callback
        print("LOG 04, urlResponse: \(urlResponse)") // I DON'T SEE THIS LOG
    }
    
    print("LOG END") // I SEE THIS LOG
    
}
```

Here is the result from Xcode output window:

```
LOG 01
LOG 02
LOG 03
LOG END
```

I don't see `LOG04`

I am sending `UIImage` parameter(paramaterImage: UIImage) in to `uploadPicture` method from below struct:

```
import UIKit
struct MyMedia {
    let key: String
    let filename: String
    let data: Data?
    let mimeType: String
    
    init?(withImage image: UIImage, forKey key: String) {
        self.key = key
        self.mimeType = "image/jpeg"
        self.filename = "temppicname.jpg"
        self.data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Missing `.resume()`. You are creating a Task, but not starting it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontask/1411121-resume

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `resume()` on the task, or it won't start:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, urlResponse, error) in
    //handle callback
    print("LOG 04, urlResponse: \(urlResponse)") // I DON'T SEE THIS LOG
}
task.resume()
```

After that, you need to make sure you're formatting the request the same way as you are in postman, otherwise the server will reject it.

I'd suggest you use something like Charles proxy to compare what your app is sending to what you're sending in Postman.

At a quick glance it looks like you're sending `p_type` etc. as request headers, but in your example from Postman, those values are part of the form.

Comment: thanks. Now I see print(LOG 04..) but i am getting statusCode = 500